# Is it a star or something else

Tags: star

I was lying down with my face up looking at the stars. Then I saw this star moving:

1. it was moving at one direction (just like airplane)
2. it's light was not blinking, just exactly as other stars both In color, brightness, size
3. it took around 90 seconds before it disappeared from my view.

This happened in eastern Nigeria

What could it be? If it's a star what kind of star is that?

Comment: Congratulations! As you can see by the duplicate question's answers , you've seen an artificial satellite. It's pretty common, especially the first few hours after sunset, or the last few hours before sunrise, when low satellites can be in sunshine even though it's still dark on the ground. If you enjoy this, you can watch for things like the International Space Station. Use a website like [in-the-sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/) or [Heavens Above](https://www.heavens-above.com/) for predictions for your location.